# Grails - prevent caching of changed resources

Tags: grails, caching

Is there a standard way to prevent caching of modified resources in Grails 2.4.4? For instance, I would like to have a gsp containing code such as

`<g:javascript src="application.js" />`

and have browsers not use a cached version of application.js when I deploy a new version of the web app. Is there a place I can update the version number without modifying the filename itself, for instance? If I modify the filename itself, it messes with my git commit history.

Comment: If you use the asset pipeline plugin this will be handled automatically for you. Since it generates a hashed version of the filename that changes when the file changes. Thus, no caching. All transparent. Great plugin. Use it. It does a whole lot more too, but I only outlined what pertains to your question.

Comment: I apparently already have version 1.9.9 compiled in. Do I need to do anything else, or will upgrading to 2.1.1 solve all?

Comment: Upgrade to any version beyond 2.0 where this was introduced. See: http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/releases.html Also read through the rest of the docs and see how to set it up and configure it for your use.

Comment: Actually, check your production source. It may already be doing this for you. View source on your page and see if the name is hashed for your include.

Comment: It turns out I need to use asset:javascript instead of g:javascript and to put the assets in the new assets folder instead of in web-app. Thanks for pointing me to where to look!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should take a look at using the Asset Pipeline plugin that is in Grails 2.4+ to manage your assets. It will make sure that browsers cache the asset until it changes for you, among other things. Take a look at the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/).

Simply moving your asset (js in this case) under the `grails-app/assets/javascript` folder and converting to `assets:javascript` instead of `g:javascript` should get you started.